# Writing text into another application's text controls (on mouse focus)

Tags: java, keyboard, focus

I need some advice on how to write text into another application's line edit when that control receives mouse focus.

For example:
I opened google.com and clicked in the "Search" field (so the mouse focus is in "Search" field).

I need to programmatically write text in that field.

I have used Robot class but some symbols are not supported. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you explain your question some more? I don't really understand it

Comment: Are you building web application or standalone application ?

Comment: If you're trying to build an application that controls another application such as a browser, then I think that Java might not be the best tool for the job. If your platform is Windows, look into using something that has been built for this sort of thing such as AutoIt. And also yeah, your question could stand to use more details.

Comment: Robot is a class that generates native mouse and keyboard events. He is trying to build an application that is able to insert text into the text controls of other (non-java) applications.

Comment: i'd like to build an application which will take from server or from text file a line of symbols and it will copy it into fields where is mouse focus